# Convert transparent part of JPEG to White color in Html2Canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, jspdf, html2canvas

I am using Html2Canvas to export document into PDF, but it converts transparent part of JPEG to Black Color(I know that's how it should go). But I want it to convert transparent background to white color. In online solutions, altering scripts (Html2Canvas or JSPDF) are suggested, but I do not want to go that way because it is not always possible. What is the best way to achieve this?

```
html2canvas(form, {
imageTimeout: 2000,
removeContainer: true,
background:'#FFF',
onrendered: function (canvas) {
    var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
    var doc = new jsPDF({
        unit: 'pt',
        format: 'a4',
    });

    // pageHeight= doc.internal.pageSize.height;
    var image = new Image();
    image = Canvas2Image.convertToJPEG(canvas);
    doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 12, 15);
    var corte = (vm.a4[1] * 1.33333) - 30;
    var croppingYPosition = corte;
    var count = (image.height) / corte;
    for (var i = 1; i < count; i++) {
        doc.addPage();
        var sourceX = 0;
        var sourceY = croppingYPosition;
        var sourceWidth = image.width;
        var sourceHeight = corte;
        var destWidth = sourceWidth;
        var destHeight = sourceHeight;
        var destX = 0;
        var destY = 0;
        var canvas1 = canvas;
        canvas1.setAttribute('height', corte * i);
        canvas1.setAttribute('width', destWidth);
        var ctx = canvas1.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(image, sourceX,
                             sourceY,
                             sourceWidth,
                             sourceHeight,
                             destX,
                             destY,
                             destWidth,
                             destHeight);
        var image2 = new Image();
        image2 = Canvas2Image.convertToJPEG(canvas1);
        var image2Data = image2.src;
        doc.addImage(image2Data, 'JPEG', 12, 15);
        croppingYPosition += destHeight;
    }
    doc.save('firstPDF.pdf');
    $('.pdfTemplates').css('width', '100%');
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Never really used Canvas2Image, but here's a hack you can try.

1. Step 1: Instead of

> convertToJPEG(canvas)

do a

> Canvas2Image.convertToPNG(canvas)

PNG should ideally preserve the transparency.

2. Step 2: Now you could draw the image onto a white canvas and thereby the result would be your JPEG with a white background

   ```
   ctx.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
   ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas1.width,canvas1.height);
   ctx.drawImage(image, sourceX,
                        sourceY,
                        sourceWidth,
                        sourceHeight,
                        destX,
                        destY,
                        destWidth,
                        destHeight);
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Anubhab. But I am not individually picking up images and putting them in the PDF. I have this already rendered page  which may span to 4 pages on PDF and the chart comes in between anywhere around. If I use convertToPNG(canvas) file size of the PDF will increase drastically ~30 MB and I would surely not want this behavior. Therefore I am using only JPEG(reduced file size) and looking for the workaround.

Comment: No doubt convertToPNG will give me white background but it will increase my file size. I am looking for the workaround which would help me to convert this canvas in JPEG and even have white background (wherever it was transparent).

Comment: Oh, ya you are right about the size! My bad. Hey could you upload a sample of the current output? I have another hack in mind but need to see if thats possible with your current output.